# Reference Error: response is not defined AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.webslesson.info/2016/09/angularjs-tutorial-with-php-fetch-select-data-from-mysql-database.html) to retrieve data from a database. The retrived data from the server is a json array and it contains these two objects:

```
[{"_id":{"$oid":"5ae81566f3a9bd1fe8002d34"},"Customer_Name":"cXQzbXlUeHRVckFvVGpoVUQxaHNoQT09","Responsiple_User":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Phone_Number":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","ID_Number":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Sale":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Resposible_Sales":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","City":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Job":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Monhthly_Income":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Number_Of_Months":"SVFxZVJkWG0vaUhxSUxFNzdrWjZCZz09","Monthly_installment_of_the_client":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","First_Payment":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Bank":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Financial_Situation":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Account":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Notes":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Date":"2018-05-01 09:21:10"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5ae8157ff3a9bd1fe8002d36"},"Customer_Name":"aGxveGF1SGxKWXpFajgzSGI0RmE0QT09","Responsiple_User":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Phone_Number":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","ID_Number":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Sale":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Resposible_Sales":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","City":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Job":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Monhthly_Income":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Number_Of_Months":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Monthly_installment_of_the_client":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","First_Payment":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Bank":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Financial_Situation":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Account":"SVFxZVJkWG0vaUhxSUxFNzdrWjZCZz09","Notes":"Wjc0TFpMbUtyUlo1bGptZ1RCOG84Zz09","Date":"2018-05-01 09:21:35"}]
```

I modified the code in the tutorial to display only the json data in the table. The problem is that I keep getting the issue of response is not defined. Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <!-- index.php !-->  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>test</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <h3 align="center">AngularJS Tutorial with PHP - Fetch / Select Data from Mysql Database</h3>  
                <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="usercontroller" ng-init="displayData()">  

                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th>First Name</th>  
                               <th>Last Name</th>  
                          </tr>  
                          <tr ng-repeat="x in names">  
                               <td>{{x.City}}</td>  
                               <td>{{x.last_name}}</td>  
                          </tr>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);  
 app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope, $http){  

      $scope.displayData = function(){  
      alert ("s");
           $http.get("data.php",$scope.names = response ).success(function(response){});  

      }  
 });  
 </script>
```

Comment: `$scope.names = response`....response is not defined.

Comment: Please check the link in the description

Comment: If you would expect people to help you you are expected to provide them with all info so that it is easy to help. And not ask them to go check links.

Comment: what ever the link says does not matter. you are trying to pass `response` to `get()` before being declare which leads to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function body and get request to this

```
$http.get("data.php").success(function(response){
    $scope.names = response;
});
```